# How to exclude from delete folder during heroku deploy?

Tags: node.js, database, heroku, deployment, directory

I deployed app on heroku which can save files with database record. Problem is, when i deploy again some changes, folder with files is new without files which were there before deploy (rows in database stay of course). How can resolve this? I want to folder "files" in root app folder stay this same during all future deploys on Heroku.

App - nodejs + express + react + postgresl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, Heroku provides an [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) file system which is wiped out after each deployment.

You need to persist data in a database (MongoDB Atlas, Heroku Postgres addon) or use an external file storage (AWS S3, Dropbox).

Check out [Files on Heroku](https://medium.com/geekculture/files-on-heroku-cd09509ed285) to see some options and examples.