# How to stop Heroku app from resetting the database every time I push to it?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

This is what my app.py file looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from os import environ

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "my_secret"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = environ.get('DATABASE_URL?sslmode=require') or 'sqlite:///my_database.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I'm fairly new to flask, but I've successfully hosted my app on Heroku. But every time I make changes to the app locally and push those changes to Heroku, the database resets, that is, it only contains what my local sqlite database contains.

How do I avoid this and keep my local and Heroku databases separate so that I can test locally with sqlite and push changes without overriding the database in my deployed Heroku app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using sqlite on heroku , if so switch to postgresql [addon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql&ved=2ahUKEwjIv-vA07DxAhXFH7cAHYPoDXMQFjAIegQIIhAC&usg=AOvVaw2gUANgpPQDEzt1RevGrEIa) of heroku because heroku don't support [sqlite](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted&ved=2ahUKEwjsiJmo07DxAhUyheYKHRX-AP8QFjAAegQIAxAC&usg=AOvVaw3NjxAanHnKWMeK61UBgGcV).

Comment: Thats not possible, see here an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/68004957/9095551